# Tensorflow prediction using tf.estimator.Estimator too slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, raspberry-pi3, boost-python

I've installed tensorflow in raspberry pi 3. It is using pretrained model and feed model function into `tf.estimator.Estimator`. My project is using c++ and currently embeds python code using boost::numpy that converts opencv matrix into numpy type, and pass it over to python function to be predicted and get results. My model function defined like below. only the propagation portion:

```
def cnn_estimator_fn(features, labels, mode):

inputs=tf.reshape(features[FEATURE_LABEL],[-1,24,16,1],name="input_node") #24 x 16 x 1, which is gray or binary image and same number of samples

conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=inputs,
                       filters=6,
                       kernel_size=[5,5],
                       padding='same',
                       activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu
                       )
#conv1 output shape: (batch_size,24,16,6)

pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2,padding='valid')

#pool1 output shape: (batch_size,12,8,6)

conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1,filters=12,kernel_size=[5,5],padding='same',activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)

#conv2 output shape: (batch_size, 12,8,12)

pool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2,padding='valid')

#pool2 output shape: (batch_size, 6,4,12)


#dense fully connected layer
pool2_flat=tf.reshape(pool2,[-1,6*4*12]) #flatten pool2 output to feed in dense layer
dense1=tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat,units=144,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
#apply dropout to avoid overfitting
dropout=tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense1,rate=0.3,training=mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

logits=tf.layers.dense(dropout,11) #input for softmax layer
```

Well, it's poorly made but i thoutht size of network is adequate for rpi3 spec. But when i ran prediction by feeding this function into tf.estimator.Estimator and call tf.estimator.predict, it takes like 3 ~ 5 seconds to predict 20 images, each shape is [24, 16, 1]. It's too slow!!

I tried following assumtion to be the problem, none was right:

**(1) Converting `vector<cv::Mat>>` into boost::numpy takes too long: no it wasn't as it took 0.00023 seconds.**

**(2) Maybe 20~30 images of shape [24,16,1] still very heavy for rpi3: no it wasn't. Even prediction of 1 image took 3~4 seconds!!.**

**(3) Maybe looping generator result of tf.Estimator.predict call is taking too long: no it wasn't. I changed to `yield_single_examples=False` and still took 3~4 seconds after 1 call to `next`.**

I call function below to pass images and predict:

```
def predict_model(img_list: list):

    predict_input = np.asarray(img_list,dtype=np.float32)

    predict_input/=255

    lpr_letter_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(cnn_estimator_fn,
    model_dir=model_dir)

    predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({FEATURE_LABEL: predict_input},
                                                  y=None,
                                                  batch_size=len(img_list),
                                                  num_epochs=1,
                                                  shuffle=False)    

    pred_dict_gen = lpr_letter_classifier.predict(predict_input_fn, yield_single_examples=False)    

    t0=time.time()

    pred_dict_list=next(pred_dict_gen)

    print("pred time: "+str(time.time()-t0))

    class_id = pred_dict_list["classes"]
    probability = pred_dict_list["probabilities"]
```

So my guess now is, maybe there's a code, where it initialize graph everytime i call `predict_model(img_list: list)` so it takes too long to predict. There, in the code,

```
t0=time.time()

pred_dict_list=next(pred_dict_gen)

print("pred time: "+str(time.time()-t0))
```

i measured time after calling next(pred_dict_gen),in  `yield_single_examples=False` mode, it took 3~4 seconds. When i changed predict mode to `yield_single_examples=True`, first call to `next(pred_dict_gen)` still took 3~4 seconds and second `next(pred_dict_gen)` call, it took 0.000034 seconds or less. So i guess first call to `next` perform prediction on whole input images and following calls are result of each image's prediction. Whoa... i strongly feel that it is not rpi3 performance problem, as i saw [squeezenet using raspberry pi 3](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/02/deep-learning-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-opencv/) performs images bigger than my input image and bigger network size took less than 2 seconds!!.

Even when i fed 1 image, not 20~30 images as input, it still took 3~4 seconds...

**What makes tf.estimator.Estimator slow from my situation?**

Comment: Straight from the link you provided: "You should never be training a neural network on the Raspberry Pi — it’s far too underpowered." ... sure, you can technically train/use neural networks on a raspi but you should also expect it to be waaaaay to slow for anything useful.

Comment: @meissner_ oh, i trained from desktop pc which has i5 processor with gt 635 gpu. It is using pretrained model for prediction. My problem is prediction time is taking too long...